# Let $G$ be a group of order 21, which acts on the set $S$. Show that if $|S|=n$ where $\gcd(21,n)=1$ then $S^G$ is nonempty.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order 21, which acts on the set $S$.  Show that if $\lvert S \rvert=n$ where $\gcd(21,n)=1$ then $S^G$ is nonempty. ($S^G$ is the subset of $S$ fixed by $G$. That is, $S^G = \{x \in S | ax=x$ for all $a \in G\}$)

Here's what I've done so far:

Since 3 and 7 are prime divisors of 21, we know by Cauchy's Theorem that G has an element of order 3 and an element of order 7.  Let $H=\langle a \rangle$ and $K=\langle b \rangle$ where $a,b \in G$ are of order 3 and 7 respectively.

A lemma in our text states that If $G$ is a finite p-group acting on $S$, then $\lvert S \rvert \equiv \lvert S^G \rvert \space \pmod p $

Thus $n \equiv \lvert S^H \rvert \space \pmod 3 \text{ and }  n \equiv \lvert S^K \rvert \space \pmod 7$.
Since $\gcd(21,n)=1$, we know $0 \not\equiv \lvert S^H \rvert \space \pmod 3 \text{ and }  0 \not\equiv \lvert S^K \rvert \space \pmod 7$

I'm not sure if I can argue from here that $0 \not\equiv \lvert S^G \rvert \space \pmod{21} $

Answer (score 2):

The result you're trying to prove is not true.  For instance, let $S=G/H\cup G/K$, with $G$ acting by translation on the cosets (so each element of $G$ maps $G/H$ to itself and $G/K$ to itself).  Then $|S|=|G/H|+|G/K|=7+3=10$ is relatively prime to $21$.  But no element of $S$ is fixed by every element of $G$.